# How to determine the associations for eager loading

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, eager-loading

I'm working on rails 3.2 and would like to implement eager loading for my pages. My model is associated with many other models and want to know how to determine the associations which I need to add inside the "include". Please help me with this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think, https://github.com/voxdolo/decent_exposure can help.

in short, you are lazily pulling data from views using helper methods, instead of passing pre-fetched data as instance variables

Comment: ok, so You need to create different scopes or class methods using eager loading.

After, expose them in controller and use in view